# Document Viewer (Evince) makes highlighted (selected) text non-graphically corrupted

Tags: pdf, evince, document

In Ubuntu Document Viewer (Evince), when text is highlighted (selected) it becomes non-graphically corrupted.
[image: Example]

How can I make all the text in particular PDF in any PDF reader looks like that all the time without being highlighted?